# Random slow POST or no POST with harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

Has anyone experience random slow POST or no POST at all with a harddrive?

I tested pluging and unplugging my hardware to see what is causing this issue.

And when I got into unplugging the harddrive, my computer enter POST like normal. I didnot experience that when unplugging my souncard, nic, change ram, change peripheral.

And I have triple tested it to confirm itu was the harddrive. Then I tried using crystaldiskinfo to look at the SMART values. Everything is normal range.

Could this is a sign of my harddrive will fail me? Sometimes when I power on it would gives weird sound. Should I start moving my data to a new harddrive?

```
-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 100 100 _16 000000000000 Read Error Rate
02 135 135 _54 000000000056 Throughput Performance
03 151 151 _24 000801A40155 Spin-Up Time
04 100 100 __0 000000000B15 Start/Stop Count
05 100 100 __5 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 100 100 _67 000000000000 Seek Error Rate
08 135 135 _20 00000000001A Seek Time Performance
09 _97 _97 __0 000000005718 Power-On Hours
0A 100 100 _60 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0C 100 100 __0 0000000007ED Power Cycle Count
C0 _98 _98 __0 000000000B19 Power-off Retract Count
C1 _98 _98 __0 000000000B19 Load/Unload Cycle Count
C2 162 162 __0 002F00170025 Temperature
C4 100 100 __0 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
C5 100 100 __0 000000000000 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 100 100 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
```

Comment: Yes, High amount of I/O errors can cause this.

Comment: Also just try replacing the SATA cable. I assume this is a desktop PC and the HDD is connected to the motherboard using a SATA cable. Do you see any CRC Error Count value in the output of SMART Values?

Comment: I updated the question with the SMART values. I will try changing the SATA cable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
It could be more than one problem:
- BIOS setting (GPT/maser boot record, legacy access or ... I forgot)
- I could also cause troubles if GPT has some strange data...
- power related questions (especially if you have many drives spinning up at once)
- not necessarily hardware related problems, but this is also possible.

One time system did not want to start at all (everything was new). Other hard drive was OK, another computer that hard drive was also OK.